# Is every number a sum of $3$ tetrahedral numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

It is known that every number can be represented by a sum of $3$ triangular numbers. According to Gauss (see formula $35$ in mathworld [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularNumber.html))
$$
\text{num}=\Delta+\Delta+\Delta
$$
I did some numerical experiments that suggest the above formula is correct when triangular numbers are replaced by tetrahedral numbers
$$
\Delta=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6
$$
if $n$ is allowed to be negative.

Is this conjecture correct?

I tried to google representation of integers by tetrahedral numbers but didn't find anything.

Comment: For positive tetrahedral numbers, this is a significant strengthening of [Pollock's tetrahedral numbers conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollock_tetrahedral_numbers_conjecture):  Every positive integer is the sum of at most five tetrahedral numbers.

Comment: This conjecture is equivalent to *Every element of $6\mathbb{Z}$ can be represented as $(x^3+y^3+z^3)-(x+y+z)$* and it probably is a very difficult problem. This is an instance of a similar problem: it is not known if $33$ can be represented as the sum of three integer cubes.

Comment: The question has now been raised on mathoverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325659/does-the-set-binom-x3-binom-y3-binom-z3-x-y-z-in-mathbb-z-contain-all

Comment: @Jack, $33$ has been done very recently, by Andrew Booker. See, e.g., https://aperiodical.com/2019/03/33-can-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three-cubes/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\Delta(n)$ for negative $n$ is allowed, then certainly the integers $t=0\dots 10000$ are all possible. The most awkward of these is $t=6398=\Delta(-1121877)+\Delta(1037512)+\Delta(665832)$. The size of the summands might give you an idea of the size of the task of seeking an explicit solution for each total $t$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I did only verify it to $t=150$.